# add shortcut to website on multiple computers VIA script or software

Tags: batch-processing, shortcut

I have several computers that I have to add a desktop shortcut to. The shortcut is just a link to a web URL. I'm wondering how you would code this in a batch script?

I can access each computer via network path and they are all kiosks, so the user is the same on them.

I imagine the code would be something like this...

PSEUDOCODE
create [shortcut to application (IE)][url] on [computer name 1][path to desktop]
create [shortcut to application (IE)][url] on [computer name 2][path to desktop]
create [shortcut to application (IE)][url] on [computer name 3][path to desktop]
etc...

Any ideas?

I'm also open to using software tools that make this process a little easier too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xcopy` or `Robocopy`.

*xcopy:*

```
xcopy /E /I /Y "\\TOKEN\Deploy\Shortcuts" "%PUBLIC%\Desktop"
```

*Robocopy:*

```
robocopy.exe "\TOKEN\Deploy\Shortcuts" "%PUBLIC%\Desktop" /MIR
```